# Ошибка обработки файла после загрузки PHP

Tags: php

Загрузка файлов происходит на ajax. Проблема в том, что если файл больше чем 2 мб., то класс для создания миниатюры не работает, вернее выдаёт ошибку типа:

```
Warning: getimagesize(Z:/home/shop/www/public/uploads/002.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\home\shop\www\admin\systems\classes\uploads.class.php on line 18

Warning: Division by zero in Z:\home\shop\www\admin\systems\classes\uploads.class.php on line 84
```

и это не весь список.

Я понял, что он выдаёт ошибку, потому что файл ещё не успел загрузится, а ему уже говорят, давай обрабатывай.

Делаю так:

```
move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'], $this -> dir . $new_name_file);

$new_image = new SimpleImage($this -> dir . $new_name_file);
$new_image -> imageresizewidth($thumb_img_resize_width);
$new_image -> imagesave($new_image -> image_type, $this -> dir . 'thumb/' . $new_name_file);
$new_image -> imageout();
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: ошибка в том что файл так и не попал в папку `public/upload`. В настройках сервера php.ini (или где то в ini_set) устанавливаются значения максимального размера загружаемого файла?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему прописав в .htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 500
php_value max_input_time 500
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
php_value post_max_size 30M
```